# Why the view does not fit on the parent view?

Tags: swift, autolayout, snapkit

I can't understand that the view does not fit on the parent view ? This screenshot shows problem with green button that button doesn't fit parent view. Red background color it is containerView.
I'm using SnapKit for constraints. Please help me. Thanks!

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKOjM.png)

```
 private lazy var scrollView = UIScrollView()
 private lazy var containerView = UIView()
 // etc
 
 // viewDidLoad
 scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
 containerView.addSubviews([boxView, addButton])
 boxView.addSubviews([titleLabelView, vStackView])
 view.addSubview(scrollView)

 // viewWillLayoutSubviews
 scrollView.snp.makeConstraints {
     $0.edges.equalToSuperview()
 }
 containerView.snp.makeConstraints {
     $0.edges.equalToSuperview()
     $0.width.equalToSuperview()
 }
 addButton.snp.makeConstraints {
     $0.height.equalTo(65)
     $0.top.equalTo(boxView.snp.bottom).offset(24)
     $0.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(40)
 }
```

Comment: I'd recommend *not immediately* putting constraints in your declarations. Rather, break this down into views/subviews. Add the constraints. And **only** then try to code what you are. There really is more to this then `lazy`, `$0.`, and everything else. This is meant with NO offense! Constraints are hard enough without using `Superview`! Take it one single step at a time!

Answer (score 0):

Without the `makeConstraints()` method can't be certain, but if it's just applying normal autolayout constraints you will need to use a negative value  for the bottom constant.

In AL a positive value means move down from the anchor, whereas you need to move the edge of the button up from the anchor (the box's bottomAnchor).

If you've come from Interface BUilder this isn't obvious as in IB the negative values are applied by tool.

`$0.top.equalTo(boxView.snp.bottom).offset(-24)`